# How to change just the css inside a DIV and not anywhere else?

Tags: css

I have this code :

```
h1, h2, h3, h4{ 
    color: red;
}
.message_rouge h1, h2, h3, h4,{color: black;}
```

Why are ALL my headers black instead of just the ones inside "message_rouge" and the rest red?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each line is it's own selector, but you're only specifying `.message_rouge` on the first one.

**Use this instead:**

```
.message_rouge h1, 
.mesage_rouge h2,
.mesage_rouge h3,
.mesage_rouge h4 {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: wow, I've been procrastinating on that "problem" for so long and it's so simple I should have asked before... Thanks a bunch to all who answered! :)

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong

```
.message_rouge h1, h2, h3, h4,{color: black;}
```

This is right

```
.message_rouge h1,.message_rouge h2,.message_rouge h3,.message_rouge h4,{color: black;}
```

Comment: Thanks nicolas. Although your answer is the same as the other one, I chose the other one simply because it was easier to read (for me, but mostly for everybody else who will ever read it).